# How to omit columns for specific rows in SQL?

Tags: sql, query-optimization

As an example:

```
select 
    pre, sze, fdm_pre, val
from 
    form_data_stage
where 
    fdm_pre in (1,2,3,4) 
order by 
    pre;
```

this will return values for all the columns `pre`, `sze`, `fdm_pre`, `val` for any of the fdm_pre values listed, i.e. (1,2,3,4).  However, I only care about the `pre` and `size` values when `fdm_pre` is 1.

I could write a query such as

```
select 
    case when fdm_pre = 1 then pre else null end as pre, 
    case when fdm_pre = 1 then sze else null end as sze,
    fdm_pre,
    val
from 
    form_data_stage 
where 
    fdm_pre in (1,2,3,4) 
order by 
    pre;
```

But, is there some standard way of dealing with this situation?  Is it generally more efficient to return all the columns, even if they aren't used?  Or, would it be better to do some conditional checking as in the second query?  The `pre` and `sze` columns are integer values.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Conditional logic in the select won't do you much good, it's the row processing that matters. This query is so simple the only thing that jumps out is indexing fdm_pre.

Comment: @Error_2646 Oracle 19.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not efficient to return all the columns when they are not used, specially if the unused columns are massive in size (`BLOB`, `CLOB`, `TEXT`, `ARRAY`, etc.).

In your particular example the columns "not returned" are small ones (measured in bytes), so it won't really matter if you produce nulls instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use execute string instead of this kind of script. In that way your desire columns should put in string and with if statement you can decide about which column is shown and which one is not necessary.
I can make a sample for you if you need.

Answer (score -1):

I think keeping the query simple and clear to read is important. I would suggest you return all the relevant columns (that might be useful) and on the app logic side deal with these 2 options of column usage.